# A software DHCP server

Tags: networking, internet, dhcp, dhcp-server

I want to run a software DHCP server, so that people can access the internet through my computer. I want to be able to do things like see what websites they are browsing. I can use software made for OSX, Linux, or Windows. Can you recommend any that have this capability?

Comment: DHCP has nothing to do with accessing the Internet through your computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is actually routing and/or NAT functionality as well as DHCP service.  Internet Connection Sharing is included with Windows.  Linux has iptables (and an assortment of GUI frontends) plus a DHCP server.  I'm not familiar with what facilities OSX provides, but I would imagine they're similar.

http://www.google.com/search?q=how+do+I+share+my+internet+connection

Comment: -1 for LMGTFY link, although the rest of the answer is solid

Comment: Really?  We hate LMGTFY here?  /sigh  And here I thought I could put a smile on the faces of some folks who downvoted him for his poorly asked question...  Guess I'm too new to the community to know all the rules yet.

Comment: we hate LMGTFY because these sites aim to be the first google result. Imagine a users frustration with a that stupid fsking "Super User" website when they google for their question and all they found was an answer telling them to google for it.